# Extract data from a URL to use in a selenium test

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, testing, automated-tests

I am testing a football betting website currently. In this website there is a different game every day. So each game has a different id in the URL. An example of this would be 
https://web-game-stage.sportgames.com/games/5b310f8967ef5ad461d75aef/
so the 5b310f8967ef5ad461d75aef is the game id. How can i extract this code from the URL and basically just make it a string??

Comment: How do you get to this url. Is it some href?

Comment: On the main page each game has a different name so i just select the name to go to the game page

Comment: Can you provide the html behind that game element? What kind of element is that and what all attributes are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after going to the game page. You get extract game id as given below.

```
String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String[] arrayURL = currentURL.split('/');
int arrLength = arrayURL.length;
String gameID = arrayURL[arrLength-1];
System.out.println("game ID = "+gameID);
```